# How to save a datatable to SQL database in a column and later retrieve that convert to pdf in a tabular format in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf

I have a requirement where I have to save a datatable to the sql db in a single column and later retrieve that on user action and convert that to pdf which looks exactly like a table. Request you to suggest the best way for this..

Mods - Please this is not a duplicated. I have to retrieve the data and convert that to a pdf in tabular format.

Answer (score 0):

Using **MigraDoc** as an open source .NET library to export a DataTable to PDF.
For exporting data table into pdf please refer [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/355353/Exporting-a-DataTable-to-PDF)

**And for saving into database**

I would create, if possible, a xml field inside the sql database and save the datatable as xml

[XML Support in Microsoft SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345117(SQL.90).aspx)

and

[C# and Vb.net example for XML data type tips in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16313/XML-data-type-tips-in-SQL-Server)

should help you

another example took from [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22831189/Saving-data-to-xml-fields-with-C-and-SQL-Server-2005-Database.html)

Comment: What format do I need to save it to database? Varbinary? and then convert that back to datatable?

Answer (score 0):

If it's data save it as data and transform it in the requester's format as you select it. If its a document save it as a document. What you suggest is the worst of all options.

Xml is an option as mentioned but you can't beat actually storing your data as data.